# Using OSM instead of Google Maps in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I want to use OSM instead of Google Maps, while I'm developing Android applications. How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also asked the question on the osm help and i got this.

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

> osmdroid provides Tools / Views to interact with OpenStreetMap-Data.
>
> The OpenStreetMapView is a (almost) full/free replacement for Androids
>   MapView class.

Here is a how to on using osmdroid in your apps

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToUseJar

osmdroid id not to be confused with Osmdroid with capital O which is a navigation app for android that uses OSM maps.

If you guys could come up with more resources, it would be appriciated.

Thank you.